# Having problems connecting to MongoDb online database

Tags: node.js, express

Hello there im having difficulties connecting to an online database. Im struggling to see where the mistake is. Here is a snippet of the code that i have been trying to run

```
//here is the connection string

const connectionString = "mongi+srv://itai<mygodisgood>@itaicluster--ss7qx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, function (err, database) {       
      const db=database.db('cars');
      const collections=db.collection('mycars'); 
})
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about the error you receive? Try log or debug the `err` inside your `.connect()` function and inspect the error

Comment: okay let me do that